# What's going on with the recommendation tag?

Tags: support, tags

Just spotted [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/3488/portable-virtual-machine-recommendation) on the front page which has been tagged with [recommendation](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/recommendation), yet when I click on the tag, it appears as though no questions have this tag.

What's going on here? Note the page for the tag states that `You are on the Featured tab`, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: Hmm. I see 82 questions on the tag page...

Comment: Odd, I can't get it to do that for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We remember your tab setting when you browse various pages that list questions. So if you last looked at the Featured tab on the main Questions page or on any tag, that setting will be preserved and applied to the next tag you look at.

However, the [recommendation](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/recommendation) tag *doesn't have* a Featured tab at all since no questions tagged [recommendation](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/recommendation) have a bounty on them, so you end up seeing 0 questions.

More info [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88036/why-did-clicking-on-a-tag-take-me-to-a-nonexistent-tab) and on the duplicate.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, but it's complicated by the fact that there are multiple pages with a `Featured` tab (i.e. [homepage](http://serverfault.com/), and [questions](http://serverfault.com/questions) page). It's the tabs on the questions page that is relevant, not the homepage. I normally view the homepage when looking at questions, and had the `active` tab selected, hence my confusion.